# Doctrine ORM: Updating Associations of an Entity - Fetch all Entities from DB?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, associations, updating

Im new to Doctrine, and using ORM's.

I want to update the join table of an entities association in Doctrine ORM.

I have 2 Entities with a join table for a Many-toMany association

**Zoos Table**

| id | zoo_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | London Zoo |
| 2 | New York Zoo |

**Animals Table**

| id | animal_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lion |
| 2 | Bear |
| 3 | Donkey |
| 4 | Otter |

**Zoos_Animals Join Table**

| zoo_id | animal_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

Historically, when not using an ORM I would post the ID's of all the animals a zoo has, then save in the following way:

```
1. DELETE FROM zoo_animals WHERE zoo_id = 1
2. FOREACH $_POST['updated_animals'] as $animal_id {
     INSERT INTO zoo_animals ($_POST['zoo_id'], $animal_id
   }
```

I've simplified this to get my point across, (I would sanitize data etc..)

But when using Doctrine, it seems that even though I have all the information I need in $_POST (an array of animal_id's), in order to update zoo_animals for zoo 1, I need to:

1. On save run a DQL query which gets all zoo info out along with it's zoo_animals
2. Build a new ArrayCollection for the Zoo's $animals property by fetching all Animals posted in $_POST['updated_animals']
3. $zoo->setAnimals($fetchedAnimals) to the ArrayCollection we just fetched
4. Flush

All I need in my join table is the animal ID's, so it seems really in-efficient that I have to fetch the entire Animal entity for each zoo_animal from the Animals table in order to update the association.

Am I missing something - is there another way to update the join table? - maybe I shouldn't bother recreating the Zoo entity and instead should just deal directly with the join table somehow?

I did also try not fetching the Animals from DB for each $_POST['updated_animals'] and instead just create the Animal with the bare minimum data needed (which I have)

```
$updatedAnimals = new ArrayCollection();
foreach ($_POST['updated_animals'] as $id){
   $animal = (new Animal())->setId(id);
   $updatedAnimals->add($animal);
}
```

But when I Flush() I get the following error

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Zoo#animals' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity

..basically doctrine doesn't recognise the Animals I created from posted animal ID's, even though they are in the animals table.

As I say, I'm new to using ORM's but all this re-fetching from the DB in order to update seems very inefficient as so I suspect Im doing something wrong.